# Wordpress bug with <select disabled>

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

I installed template, and i needed use some linked lists on my post. So, i tryed to do next steps: 1) wrote to "functionss.php" this code:

```
 function exec_php($matches){
    eval('ob_start();'.$matches[1].'$inline_execute_output = ob_get_contents();ob_end_clean();');
    return $inline_execute_output;
}
function inline_php($content){
    $content = preg_replace_callback('/\[exec\]((.|\n)*?)\[\/exec\]/', 'exec_php', $content);
    $content = preg_replace('/\[exec off\]((.|\n)*?)\[\/exec\]/', '$1', $content);
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'inline_php', 0);
```

So, now i can use php in my post. 
In post i've done this:

```
<select class="mark" style="width:100%;">
<option value='0'>Выберите Автомобиль</option>
[exec]
global $wpdb;
$query= $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM `wp_mark` ");
$i=0;
for($i;$i<count($query);$i++){


echo "<option value='".$query[$i]->id."'>".$query[$i]->mark."</option>";
}
[/exec]
</select>


<script>
jQuery(function(){

var id = jQuery(".mark").val();
jQuery.ajax({ 
    type:"POST",
    url: "wp-content/command.php",
    data: {id_mark: id},
    success: function(data){
          jQuery(".command").html(data);

}
});
       jQuery(".mark").change(function(){
var id = jQuery(".mark").val();
if(id==0){
}
jQuery.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "wp-content/command.php",
    data: {id_mark: id},
    success: function(data){
          jQuery(".command").html(data);
}
});
});
});
</script>
<span class="command" disabled></span>
```

So, all clear: I have one select, which includes car's srerias from db. It read good and clear. So the second action is Post-response to "command.php", where I'm getting car's models from db, it's not interesting I guess, but this is a code of "command.php":

```
<script>
   // jQuery(function(){
      //  jQuery('select[name="command"]').change(function(){
     //       alert(jQuery('select[name="command"]').val());
     //   });
  //  });
</script>
<?php
require_once ('../wp-config.php');
global $wpdb;
?>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['id_mark']) && !empty($_POST['id_mark'])){
$id = intval ($_POST['id_mark']);
$query1= $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM `wp_model` WHERE `id_mark` = $id");

echo "<select name='command'>";
    $i1=0;
    for($i1;$i1<count($query1);$i1++){
        var_dump($query1[$i1]->model);
    echo "<option value='".$query1[$i1]->model."</option>";
}
    echo "</select>";
}
else
{
 echo "<select name='command' disabled><option value='0'>--Change car--</option></select>";
}

?>
```

so, i really have 2 dropdownlists, and can change seria and model of car. But!
On every post, and in localhost/WordPress/wp-admin page I have disabled select:

```
<select name='command' disabled><option>--�������� ������--</option></select><!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="ie8 wp-toolbar"  lang="ru-RU">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 8) ]><!-->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="wp-toolbar"  lang="ru-RU">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

I thought that this is because my mistakes in code, and deleted everything connected with "select", but it's still there. 
Then i tryed to find a file which doing this request, and it was my empty "command.php". Then i delete this file, i caught an error in console, but this disabled select is still there! I tried to find some response but can't do it.
Do you have any idea?

Comment: Can you search for name='command' in all your project?

Comment: Yes, there are about 1000 usages of this word in all project (localhost/wordpress)

Comment: Try to make slight modifications one by one and test whether the modification is applied. If so, you found the place to look at.

Comment: I wrote that I deleted all code which I'd  written before this select appeared, but i's still there, and not only on one of posts: it's everywhere in wordpress.

Comment: I know, but you really need to fix the code, which means that you should take a look at where this code is written (if a thousand times, then a thousand times) and fix the problem everywhere, possibly by creating a function to help you and use it on all occurrences, so you will have the code at one place and the next time your labor will be reduced.